# Posting a tweet on the Twitter timeline using "TwitterOAuth"

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to post a feed on Twitter using `TwitterOAuth`. I have two PHP scripts, `redirect.php`, and `callback.php` that work as follows.

```
redirect.php -> twitter auth -> callback.php
```

Whatever session key/values stored upon calling redirect.php are lost when callback.php is called for some reason.

The both PHP files reside in the same domain and HTTPS is used all the way through.
`session_start()` is used in the both scripts right before storing and fetching session data.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Apache was not able write session files to a directory(in my case, `/var/lib/php/session`) specified in the php.ini.

Granting the write permission for this directory to Apache has solved the problem.